# How do actors wear winter clothing in LA during outdoor simulated snow scenes?

Tags: film-techniques, the-office

When a scene is set in a northern climate winter, how do actors wear winter clothing in LA during simulated snow scenes?

An example is "The Office" in the parking lot.

They don't appear like they're sweating. I couldn't imagine wearing an winter coat, scarf, etc with the temperature in the 80s. Do they have outdoor ACs running?

Comment: Related, though not a dupe imo. https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96400/25773

Comment: Some North American Productions are not filmed in LA but in other common filming locations, included Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada.  So I guess sometimes actors in winter scenes are glad to wear heavy clothing, depending on where they are filming.i

Comment: Here is a link to  a similar question.  https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97521/actors-overly-dressed-for-weather-in-40-60s-movies/97537#97537

Answer (score 5):

It's usually mitigated by keeping their exposure time down as far as possible - they can do the blocking and rehearsal in lighter clothing and use stand-ins wherever possible, then the principals go wait somewhere without their top-coats etc in a cooled location until the scene is completely ready to go.

If they're lucky, that cooled location is an air-conditioned building or trailer. If not, it's an umbrella or just somewhere in the shade. 
It wouldn't be too much to imagine they could rig an [EZ-Up](https://www.ezup.eu) or equivalent, which are ubiquitous on any set; with a portable aircon unit.

The thing about making film/TV is it's nowhere near as glamorous as it looks. 
Sometimes people do just have to tough it out. Wearing winter clothing when it's 32° in the shade is just one of those times.

Comment: 32 degrees in the Fahrenheit scale used in the USA is equal to zero degrees Celsius or 273.15 degrees Kelvin. 32 degrees Celsius is 89.6 degrees Fahrenheit or 305.15 degrees Kelvin.  32 degrees Kelvin is minus 402.07 degrees Fahrenheit or minus 273.15 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Are you an equivalency bot?

Comment: @M.A.Golding 32 kelvins = -241.15 degrees Celsius

Comment: @Jason P Sallinger  According to Kruga's correction I am not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a somewhat similar question.

[Actors Overly Dressed For Weather in 40-60s movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97521/actors-overly-dressed-for-weather-in-40-60s-movies/97537#97537)[1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97521/actors-overly-dressed-for-weather-in-40-60s-movies/97537#97537)

Part of the answers to both questions is that actors often have to be uncomfortable during filming for the sake of making a good movie or episode, just as members of many other professions and occupations often have to be physically uncomfortable on the job.